# Axis Stub client can not parse envelope

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-data-services-server

I have one web sevice on WSO2 AS and it is calling another web service from WSO2 DSS then returning exactly the same objects. I am using axis2 stub for calling web service. When i call WSO2 AS web service it could not parse the envelope and all objects return null.

Do you have any suggestion, you could see the results from dss and application server. I could not parse the result from application server on axis2 stub.

Thanks

WSO2 DSS Web Service Result

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <productProfileApps xmlns="http://namespace2">
         <productProfileApp productId="8B5BB70B-26EA-4862-914B-A074B16D2BDB" applicationId="2B33438B-DDF5-4BE7-A2C6-934A4DF48B17"/>
         <productProfileApp productId="8B5BB70B-26EA-4862-914B-A074B16D2BDB" applicationId="24162E44-CA7C-4AC6-9A3E-9EDE3B484E1D"/>
      </productProfileApps>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

WSO2 AS Result

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getProductProfileAppsResponse xmlns:ns="https://namespace1" xmlns:ax2480="http://namespace2/xsd" xmlns:ax2478="http://namespace3/xsd" xmlns:ax2482="https://namespace1/xsd" xmlns:ax2476="http://namespace4/xsd">
         <ns:return productId="8B5BB70B-26EA-4862-914B-A074B16D2BDB" applicationId="2B33438B-DDF5-4BE7-A2C6-934A4DF48B17" />
         <ns:return productId="8B5BB70B-26EA-4862-914B-A074B16D2BDB" applicationId="24162E44-CA7C-4AC6-9A3E-9EDE3B484E1D"/>
      </ns:getProductProfileAppsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: First you do not need to keep two service layers. You can directly call DSS. And what you mean by could not parse the results?

Comment: Hi Ratha,
Stub client return null for all objects on envelope. However when i looked the envelope there is a variable on it.

Comment: Still not clear.I do not see any difference between AS and DSS results. Both are same? can you provide more details? your axis2 client sample code and the return results?

Comment: I have created my axis2 client with axis2 maven plugin. I am using 1.6.2. When i try to access productId or applicationId values from axis2 client they are returning null object on AS call.